# how to throw an exception if the object that is being added has a duplicate

Tags: java

I have to add a new object to an array but throw an exception if that object already exists.I don't know what to add after 'throw___________;'.
I have made the object class and also a class to hold an array of that object.I have also done the part where i have to add it to the array but i don't know what exception to throw if the object already exists in that array.

Comment: `throw MyCustomException();`  Where you need to make `CustomException` and let it extend `Exception` i believe. You are most likely going to call it `DuplicateException` and do `throw new DuplicateException()`

Comment: Depends what exception you want to throw?

Comment: I'd suggest using a Set http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 17):

The straightforward to do is throw an existent exception. You can do something like.

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException();
```

Or use the constructor with String parameter

```
throw new IllegalArgumentException("The value is already in the list.");
```

You can see the documentation of [IllegalArgumentException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) on oracle website.

If you prefer to use a custom exception. You need to follow the suggestion of @3kings. But you have to user the `new`operator. For example, `throw new MyCustomeException()`.

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom exception `class` like the one below:

```
public class CustomException extends Exception
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1997753363232807009L;

    public CustomException()
    {
    }

    public CustomException(String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public CustomException(Throwable cause)
    {
        super(cause);
    }

    public CustomException(String message, Throwable cause)
    {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public CustomException(String message, Throwable cause, 
                                       boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace)
    {
        super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    }

}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
throw new CustomException("blah blah blah");
```

Refer this link: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-custom-exception-example/

Answer (score 0):

Create a `RuntimeException` by making a new class that extends `RuntimeException`. Or, you could just use a `Set` rather than an array. Thus, you would get automatic duplicate-checking.

Comment: Most implementations of `Set` silently overwrite the old value instead of throwing.